# How do you support Ezreal?

Tags: league-of-legends

I main supports. I do a job good enough, by feeding my AD carry, denying the other bot lane, roaming or pulling off clutch support moves, to "carry" the game more often than not. The one exception to that rule is Ezreal. Unlike other AD carries, I don't feel I make anything happen with Ezreal other than hope he is good enough to out-play our opponents.

From my point of view, he has poor harass and poor burst. I can't play a kill lane Leona or Alistar as we'll likely get out-DPSed. I can't play a passive Soraka, but it feels like we're getting denied too easily. Blitzcank is about the only support I have had some success with, but even there it feels considerably more difficult than when I play Blitzcrank with other lane partners. Ezreal really feels like laning with a bad Corki.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most important part of support is going to be the communication.  **This needs to start before you select your support.** You won't be able to pick the right support if you don't know Ez's playstyle.

Some Ez's might want to go aggressive.  You're right about Ez lacking the ability to blow an AD up quickly.  However, his poke is significant.  Pair him with a Sona, especially if you ban out Soraka, and you can force the enemy out of lane. Many Ez's though prefer to sit back and farm, doing damage once he's completed a solid part of his first damage item.  In this case, Soraka or Jana will be a better compliment.

Recognize that the game isn't going to be won in the lane.  It's going to be that you enabled him to farm well enough to be a force in team fights.  Just because you're not getting kills or doing anything exciting doesn't mean you're a bad support.

I also prefer to get exhaust over heal or CV. Lots of people want to dive in on Ez.  Having an exhaust to help peel for him can be crucial.

Comment: I think that's the best advice. With Ezreal, I can't really pick only based on the champion. I need to know how the players plays him since he can do both.

Answer (score 0):

You support him just like you would any other AD carry. Try convincing your Ezreal lane mate to max his w first over his q because the damage from the w per level is better then his q. Along with that the debuff from his w should let you trade with out too much of a problem in a kill lane. A weakness that Ezreal has is his lack of minion clearing power outside of his ult so if the other bot lane is pushing he can lose some of his farm to the tower.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the best supports I find for Ezreal are:

- Janna : Can easily engage or disengage when needed, has a shield to protect Ezreal.
- Taric: A reliable CC stun and heal. Provides good sustain and can be aggressive when needed.
- Sona: Good poke and sustain. Ult can be used to engage or disengage.
- Leona:Lots of CC and sunlight procs to increase your burst damage.
- Alistar: Great CC to protect, while also providing sustain and helps you to burst people down.

The common factor here really is supports who can both be aggressive and protect. Kill potential is nice but you also want to be able to survive if something does go wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I always go taric sona or soraka
Depending on the play style of the ez 
if the ez says he relays on q a lot I go soraka
If he wants to play aggressive I go taric
Or sona for a farm lane with some trades

Answer (score -1):

Well, I always go Nami with an Ezreal because the synergy is really overpowered. If you can get the stun follower up by a Q on a squishy target you've basically done like 1/2 of their health